# Firebase deploy fails with "each then should return a value or throw promise"

Tags: javascript, push-notification, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

```
'use-strict'

 const functions = require('firebase-functions');

 const admin=require('firebase-admin');

    admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


  exports.pushNotification=functions.firestore.
  document("Users/{user_id}/Notification/{notification_Id}").onWrite((change, 
  context)=> {
  const user_id=context.params.user_id;
  const notification_Id=context.params.notification_Id;

   return admin.firestore().collection("Users").doc(user_id)
  .collection("Notification").doc(notification_id).get().then(queryResult => {
const from_user_id=queryResult.data().from;
const from_data=admin.firestore().collection("Users").doc(from_user_id).get();
const to_data=admin.firestore().collection("Users").doc(user_id).get();

  return Promise.all([from_data,to_data]).then(result => {
  const from_email=result[0].data().email;
  const to_email=result[1].data().email;
  console.log("from " + from_email + " to " + to_email);

});

 });

});
```

It has 1 warning and 1 error.

warning is avoid nested promises.

error is (each then should return a value or throw promise / always return)..........

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Salam sir  AbhinavD

Comment: I solve my problem thanksss alottt

Comment: Hi i have some problem Are you there?

Comment: You are very good in error finding

Comment: Hi am working on place autocomplete suggetion but i dont found place sdk for androd api update  om console and now only place api present on console i enabke it but get error places api accesss not configure plz help me plz